# Solving $n^{th}$ power residue of a congruence

Tags: number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem, primitive-roots

I'm given $x^2$ ≡ -1 mod 365

I know that 365 = $5*73$ so then my congruence becomes,

$x^2$ ≡ -1 mod 5 and $x^2$ ≡ -1 mod 73

Since $(-1)^2$ ≡ 1 mod 5 and $(-1)^{36}$ ≡ 1 mod 73 implies that there exist solutions and since d = 2 for both then I know there are 2 solutions for both mod 5 and mod 73 (so 4 total solutions, right?)

my problem is that I'm not sure how to solve the linear congruence that I'm left with

If my solutions for mod 5 are $x_0$, $x_1$ and mod 73 are $y_0$, $y_1$

I think i'm suppose to solve the linear congruence in the form

- x ≡ $x_0$ mod 5 , x = $y_0$ mod 73
- x ≡ $x_0$ mod 5 , x = $y_1$ mod 73
- x ≡ $x_1$ mod 5 , x = $y_0$ mod 73
- x ≡ $x_1$ mod 5 , x = $y_1$ mod 73

Am I suppose to apply the Chinese Remainder theorem to solve? If so how do I know what my $x_0$, $x_1$ and $y_0$, $y_1$ are in the first place? If anyone can point me in the direction to solve that would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to solving for $x$ when you have $x \equiv a \pmod 5$ and 
$x \equiv b \pmod{73}$

The "brute force" solution looks like this.

\begin{align}
    x &= 5m + a \\
    x &\equiv b \pmod{73} \\
    \hline
    5m + a &\equiv b \pmod{73} \\
    5m &\equiv b-a \pmod{73} \\
    m &\equiv 44(b-a) \pmod{73} \\
    m &= 44(b-a) + 73n \\
    \hline
    x &= 5(44(b-a)+73n) + a \\
    x &= 220b - 219a + 365n \\
    x &\equiv 220b - 219a \pmod{365} \\
    x &\equiv 146a - 145b \pmod{365}
\end{align}

$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 5 \implies x \in \{2,3\}$
$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{73} \implies x \in \{27,46\}$ {I used Wolfram Alpha to solve this.}

\begin{array}{r|r|r}
    x \mod 5 & x \mod{73} & x\mod{365} \\
    a & b& 146a-145b \\
    \hline
    2 & 27 &   27\\\   
    3 & 46 &  -27\\
    2 & 46 & -173\\
    3 & 27 &  173\\
\end{array}